# Finding ratio of area of regions bounded by y = tan(x) and an ellipse

Tags: trigonometry, area, coordinate-systems

Q: Find $A = a + b$, where $\frac{a}{b}$ is the ratio of the area of the regions bounded by curve $y = \tan(x)$ and $\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2} + y^2 = 1$, a and b are coprimes.

I thought of assuming point  $ (\frac{\pi\cos(x)}{2}, \sin(x))$ on the ellipse.

So, it also satisfies the first curve, so, $\sin(x) = \tan(\frac{\pi\cos(x)}{2})$

I am unable to proceed after this

Comment: Doesn't $\tan x$ cut the ellipse into two identical regions?

Comment: Is it asking the ratio of the areas of the two region of the ellipse formed by the the curve $y = \tan (x)$?

Comment: The question from my material says a/b is the 'ratio of area of region bounded by the 2 curves'... So @sudeep5221 i think your interpretation is correct

Comment: @user170231 how to mathematically prove that?

Comment: Notice what happens when you replace $(x,y)$ with $(-x,-y)$. Do you know what this transformation does?

Comment: It is symmetric about O @TanishAgarwal rotate it 180 deg it still looks the same

Comment: Alright, understood that the areas are equal, thanks!